# OAuthException using Socialite with facebook - "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-socialite

I have been using Socialite for a few days with Facebook without issue. Today, I started getting this error.

```
{ "error": 
    { 
       "message": "An active access token must be used to query information 
        about the current user.", "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 2500, "fbtrace_id": "FTvIz9t1LT+"
   }
}
```

The error seems straight forward but I can't seem to see a solution online. Is there a way to reset my access_token using Socialite.

Please note: I pretty much followed this [tutorial](https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-socialite-facebook-login.html#.WNmDqPkrKUk)

The error is in the callback when I try and get the

```
$userProvider try { 
    $userProvider = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
} catch (Exception $e) {
   Log::info('Callback Error ' . $e->getMessage());
   return Redirect::to('redirect');
}
```

Thanks, Rich

Comment: Not familiar with this API, but most auth tokens in OAuth providers expire, so I think you need a refresh token if this is OAuth 2.0.  Without that the user will have to log back in.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This was happening to me also. I fixed it running `composer update` and then `composer dump-autoload`. This will update Socialite to v2.0.21

Cheers

Comment: Hi there,

Thanks for the tip but I'm still having the same issue.  I verified that composer updated to Socialite to v2.0.21 and cleared every cache I could find but same error message.  Did the dump-autoload as well.

Were there any other steps you took that may have added to your success?

Thanks,
Rich

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me too!

Comment: This worked thank you! But would you mind telling us what really caused the problem?

Answer (score 4):

It is because v2.2 of Facebook API is no longer available. Update the laravel/socialite package:

`composer update laravel/socialite`

This way it won't affect your other packages.

Answer (score 2):

i think problem is parsing the token so changing this 2 lines should fix the problem

https://github.com/laravel/socialite/pull/214/files#diff-b221dafd8a91f5753288a2d8603cef25